# If $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is compact, then every equicontinuous set $\chi \subset C(K;\mathbb{R}^{m})$ is uniformly equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, equicontinuity

> Prove that if $K \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is compact, then every equicontinuous set $X \subset C(K;\mathbb{R}^{m})$ is uniformly equicontinuous.

I don't know any criteria to show that a given set is uniformely equicontinuous so, I tried to show this only by definition, but I could not. Would anyone have any suggestions?

Is it necessary to write down the definition of equicontinuous and uniformly equicontinuous set?

---

*Edit.* Using Daniel Fischer hint:

**Proof.** By hypothesis, for each $x \in K$, given $\epsilon > 0$, there is $\delta_{x} > 0$ such that if $x,y_{x} \in K$
$$\Vert x - y_{x} \Vert < \delta_{x} \Longrightarrow \Vert f(x) - f(y_{x}) \Vert < \epsilon,\quad \forall f \in X.$$
Note that $\bigcup_{x \in K} B_{\delta_{x}}(x)$ is an open cover of $K$ and this, has a Lebesgue Number, that is, there is $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in K$, exist an open $U$ of the cover such that $B_{\delta}(x) \subset U$. Thus, for every $x,y \in K$, if $\Vert x - y \Vert < \delta$ then $x,y \in U$ for some $U$ of the cover. Therefore
$$\Vert f(x) - f(y) \Vert \leq \Vert f(x) - f(y_{x}) \Vert + \Vert f(y_{x}) - f(y) \Vert < 2\epsilon,\quad \forall f \in X.$$
Then, $X$ is uniformly equicontinuous.

Is correct?

Comment: It's not necessary to write the definitions down, but one must know them. The two ways to prove it that come to mind first are a) using the Lebesgue number of a covering, and b) an indirect proof (assume $\chi$ is not uniformly equicontinuous, then deduce that $\chi$ cannot be equicontinuous). Maybe a third just popped up. If you know the right version of Ascoli's theorem, you know that an equicontinuous $\chi$ is relatively compact, in particular totally bounded. From that you can get uniform equicontinuity using the fact that every finite set in $C(K;\Bbb R^m)$ is uniformly equicontinuous.

Comment: Overall, it's quite similar to the proof that every continuous function on a compact domain is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @DanielFischer see my edit, please.

Comment: Your notation at the end is a bit unfortunate, I'd rather call the point $z$ than $y_x$. And it may also be better to use $B_{\delta_z}(z)$ instead of $U$ before that too. But your proof is correct, and that's what counts.

Comment: @DanielFischer, I'll use your suggestions! Thank you!

Comment: If you know uniform spaces, you may appreciate the following way: If $X,Y$ are uniform spaces, a family $\mathscr{F}\subset F(X,Y)$ is equicontinuous if and only if $$\bigcap_{f \in \mathscr{F}} (f\times f)^{-1}(V)\tag{$\ast$}$$ is a neighbourhood of the diagonal $\Delta_X$ for every entourage $V$ of $Y$. And $\mathscr{F}$ is uniformly equicontinuous if and only if $(\ast)$ is an entourage of $X$ for every entourage $V$ of $Y$. Every neighbourhood of the diagonal of a compact Hausdorff space is an entourage. [Don't know if Hausdorff is necessary.]

Comment: @DanielFischer I still don't have much knowledge about general topology. Coincidentally, it is one of the next courses that I will do in the master's degree. Do you have any book suggestions for me to start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the set $C(X,\mathbb{R}^m)$ of all continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$. On this set, consider the distance:$$d(f,g)=\begin{cases}\sup\left\{d\bigl(f(x),g(x)\bigr)\,\middle|\,x\in X\right\}&\text{ if }(\forall x\in X):d\bigl(f(x),g(x)\bigr)\leqslant1\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$Now, consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}h\colon&K&\longrightarrow&C(X,\mathbb{R}^m)\\&k&\mapsto&\left(\begin{array}{ccc}X&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}^m\\f&\mapsto&f(k)\end{array}\right).\end{array}$$It is not hard to prove that $h$ is continuous if and only if $X$ is equicontinuous and that $h$ is uniformly continuous if and only if $X$ is uniformly equicontinuous. Now, use the compacity of $K$ and the fact that a continuous function from a compact metric space into a matric space is always uniformly continuous.

Comment: Nice! A very elegant demonstration!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

With **pointwise** equicontinuity, for any $\epsilon > 0$ and for each $x \in K$, there exists $\delta(\epsilon,x) > 0$ such that $|f(y) - f(x)| < \epsilon/2$ for every $f$ when $|y-x| < \delta(\epsilon,x)$.

If $K$ is compact then there is a finite set $\{x_1 , \ldots, x_n\}$ such that

$$K \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^n B(x_j,\delta(\epsilon,x_j)/2)$$

Take $\delta(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{2} \min(\delta(\epsilon,x_1) \ldots, \delta(\epsilon,x_n))$. For any $x,y \in K$, we have $|x - x_j| < \frac{1}{2} \delta(\epsilon,x_j) < \delta(\epsilon,x_j)$ for some $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$. If $|y - x| < \delta(\epsilon)$, we also have $|y - x_j| \leqslant |y-x| + |x - x_j| < \delta(\epsilon,x_j)$

Now uniform equicontinuity follows , since $|x-y| < \delta(\epsilon)$ implies that for every $f$,

$$|f(y) - f(x)| \leqslant |f(y) - f(x_j)| + |f(x) - f(x_j)| < \epsilon$$